# SignalR with multiple database configuration

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to configure SignalR notification for multiple database. 
I've a single hub connection, Assume If I get notification from DB1 to API>> dependency_OnChange method, how to identify that the notification is from DB1?
I'm getting notification from DB1 and DB2 to API and I want to send message to the users connected to the respective DB.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: I think you can find your answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045566/push-notifications-in-signalr-from-multiple-databases

Comment: No, the above link is not what I expected. I need to find from which database notification is triggered.

Comment: @MaheshM did you ever find a solution for SignalR to have multiple database configurations?